# EWW Stuck on Contacting Host!

Tags: eww

I am trying to use the multiple websites search function in EWW. One example is the search box on wikipedia.org that you reach by pressing jump to search. When I confirm my search I get stuck on Contacting host: :80

I have tried adding `(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")` to my .emacs file, but it does not help. I have the same problem on Debian Buster running Emacs 26.1 and Fedora 32 running Emacs 26.3.

I can reach the Wikipedia articles by searching with duckduckgo in EWW, so the problem seems to be related to the multiple websites search function in EWW.

Does anyone know how to solve the issue of being stuck on contacting host?